# How to resolve concurrency migration conflicts in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am looking for a solution to resolve concurrency migration conflicts in Enitity Framework Core.

The problem arises when two teammembers work in parrallel on the new migrations. During pull request the second migration is not getting executed as it was conducted on the database snapshot which in not valid any more because the fist migration had change the database. In EF6 this had to be resolved by applying dummy empty migration and merging the source code versions, after that creating again migration that was not executed.

I have heard during one of the conference that this problem had been resolved in EF Core because now it is possible to edit database snapshot file manually in put the database snapshot file in sync with the first concurrent changes. Search through the Internet for the answers but found nothing.

Comment: Why not solve it the way source control conflicts are solved? One of the teams updates to the latest and bases their migration on top of it.

Comment: Problem arises when there are two developers working in parallell. EF Core database migration is first change that is implemented and the rest of the new functionality is build on top of the migration. Reverting changes with the migration would mean reverting whole code connected with the functionalities. Moreover this problem is encountered while merging code on the pull request, so at the end.

Comment: I don't see it that way. If you are going code-first, the migration is the last step of the process, which is very simple, automatic and can be triggered at any time. In other words, you have two parallel developments, one of them checks-in first, the other updates (the code base) and generates the migration AFTER the merge.